# referencing class methods in class lists in Python

Tags: python, class, reference

I am writing a class in Python 2.6.2 that contains a lookup table.   Most cases are simple enough that the table contains data.  Some of the cases are more complex and I want to be able call a function.  However, I'm running into some trouble referencing the function.

Here's some sample code:

```
class a:
    lut = [1,
           3,
           17,
           [12,34],
           5]
```

Where `lut` is static, and is expected to be constant as well.

and now I wan to do the following:

```
class a:
    def spam0(self):
        return (some_calculation_based_on_self)

    def spam1(self):
        return (a_different_calculation_based_on_self)

    lut = [1,
           3,
           17,
           [12,34],
           5,
           self.spam0
           self.spam1]
```

This doesn't compile because `self.spam0` and `self.spam1` are undefined.  I tried using `a.spam` but that is also undefined. How can I set `lut[5]` to return a reference to `self.spam`?

**Edit:** This is what I plan to do:

(continuing the definition of `class a`):

```
import inspect

# continue to somewhere in the definition of class a

def __init__(self, param):
    self.param = param

def eggs(self):
    tmp = lut[param]
    if (insect.isfunction(tmp)): # if tmp is self.spam()
        return tmp()             # should call it here
    return tmp
```

So I want to either return a simple value or run some extra code, depending on the parameter.

**Edit:**  `lut` doesn't have to be a class property, but the methods `spam0` and `spam1` do need to access the class members, so they have to belong to the class.

I'm not sure that this is the best way to do this.  I'm still in the process of working this out.

Comment: Would you please explain your question? It seem to me that most of us didn't understand what you need...

Comment: This isn't sensible, since the parameter is provided when the object in constructed.  The "lut" business can be done in `__init__` and the final value computed.  The "eggs" method can be a simple property that returns a value computed by `__init__`.  Your design must be incomplete; please provide a more complete code snippet.

Comment: Few more questions to better understand the problem: 1) is lut "static", that is, will it change during the life of instances of a? 2) lut members need to be bound methods or can be simple functions? 3) must lut be a class property? 4) which version of python are we talking about? 5) are you sure this is the only/best way to accomplish what you have to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivial:

```
class a:
    @classmethod
    def spam(cls):
        # not really pass, but you get the idea
        pass

    lut = [1,
           3,
           17,
           [12,34],
           5,
           spam]


assert a().lut[-1] == a.spam
assert a.spam() is None
```

Comment: and how do I call `a().lut[-1]` as a class method?

Comment: So inside of `a` I can call `self.lut[-1](self)`. That does the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

In the clas body, you're creating the class; there is no `self`, so you obviously cannot yet refer to `self.anything`. But also within that body there is as yet no `a`: name `a` gets bound AFTER the class body is done. So, although that's a tad less obvious, in the body of class `a` you cannot refer to `a.anything` either, yet.

What you CAN refer to are bare names of class attributes that have already been bound: for example, you could simply use `5, spam]` at the end of your list `lut`. `spam` will be there as a function, as you say at one point that you want; not as a method, and most definitely NOT as a class method (I don't see `classmethod` ANYWHERE in your code, why do you think a class method would magically spring into existence unless you explicitly wrap a function in the `classmethod` builtin, directly or by decorator?) -- I suspect your use of "class method" does not actually refer to the class-method type (though it's certainly confusing;-).

So, if you later need to call that function on some instance `x` of `a`, you'll be calling e.g. `a.lut[-1](x)`, with the argument explicitly there.

If you need to do something subtler it may be possible to get a bound or unbound method of some sort at various points during processing (after the class creation is done, or, if you want a bound instance method, only after a specific instance is instantiated). But you don't explain clearly and completely enough what exactly it is that you want to do, for us to offer very detailed help on this later-stage alternatives.

Comment: I actually don't know what a *`classmethod`* is in Python, so I can't have been referring to that. :-)

Answer (score 4):

While you are in the scope of the class, you can just write

```
class A:
    def spam(self):
        pass

    lut = [1, 2, 3, spam]

a = A()
print a.lut
```

gives

```
[1, 2, 3, <function spam at 0xb7bb764c>]
```

Don't forget that this is a *function* in your lookup table, not a number as you probably intended. You probably want to solve another problem.

Comment: I indeed want a function, not a number.  I'll call the function in with relevant parameters in this case.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.  How can I use `a.lut[3]` as a method call?  a.lut[3]() doesn't work.

Comment: You can make `lut` an instance of a class that defines `__getitem__`, but I don't think that is the problem you want to solve. I suggest you open another question and describe your problem in broader terms.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that there's no such thing as static, or constant, in Python. Just make it easy to read. Here's an example which generates a cached version of `lut` per object:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__cached_lut = None

    def spam0(self):
        return (some_calculation_based_on_self)

    def spam1(self):
        return (a_different_calculation_based_on_self)

    @property
    def lut(self):
         if self.__cached_lut is None:
             self.__cached_lut = [1,
               3,
               17,
               [12,34],
               5,
               self.spam0()
               self.spam1()]
         return self.__cached_lut

a = A()
print a.lut
```

Comment: but in this case I'm calling both `spam0` and `spam1` each time I instantiate the class.  These can be (and in fact are in my example) very time-consuming functions.

By the way, what does `@property` mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. Is this what you mean?

```
class a:
    lut = [1,
           3,
           17,
           [12,34],
           5]

    def __init__(self):
        self.lut.append(self.spam)

    def spam(self, a):
        print "this is %s" % a

b = a()
b.lut[-1](4)
```

this will output: "this is 4".

Comment: This is what I mean.  Is there any way to do this *not* in the constructor, but rather as part of the definition of `lut[]`?

Comment: I see that Otto Allmendinger shows how to do that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351669/referencing-class-methods-in-class-lists-in-python/1351694#1351694

Comment: No, Otto's answer gives you unbound methods instead of bound methods, so it won't work like this.  You'd have to call it as `b.lut[-1](b, 4)`, which is awkward.

Comment: This one has a serious bug: a.lut is shared.  `b = a(); print b.lut; c = a(); print c.lut`

Answer (score 0):

You want the function to be bound to the class.  None of the answers seem to address this.

This won't be done automatically; when you do this:

```
class a:
    def spam(self): print self
    lut = [1, spam]
```

`lut[1]` is spam itself, not a bound method to an object, so you can't simply call `lut[1]()`; you'd have to call `lut[1](self)`.

If you specifically want to be able to include functions in the list that can be called directly, you need to arrange for the functions to be bound, which means referencing them from an instance and not the class.  To do this, you'd probably want to initialize this list from `__init__`:

```
class a:
    def spam(self): print self
    def __init__(self):
        self.lut = [1, self.spam]
```

and now `self.lut[1]()` is correct, since it's a bound method.

This all has the advantage that other functions can be placed in the list for other purposes, possibly bound to other objects or otherwise not expecting a parameter.

It has the disadvantage that you aren't reusing the list between instances; this may or may not matter to you.

Answer (score -1):

You're going to need to move the definition of `a.lut` outside of the definition of `a`.

```
class a():
    def spam():pass

a.lut = [1,2,3,a.spam]
```

If you think about it, this makes perfect sense.  Using self wouldn't work because `self` is actually only defined for class methods for which you use the parameter "`self`". `self` has no special meaning in Python and is not a reserved word; it is simply the conventional argument passed to bound class methods, but could also be `this`, or `foo`, or whatever you want.

Referring to `a.lut` doesn't work because the definition of `a` isn't complete yet.  How should Python know, at that point in the code, what a is?  In the scope of `a`'s class definition, `a` itself is still undefined.

Comment: Note that in this solution (to later call the function via the lut on an instance x) you ALSO need `a.lut[-1](x)`, just like with the approach I suggest, because `a.spam` here is an unbound method and doesn't offer you any extra functionality wrt the function I'm using, just one extra error check.

Comment: @Alex, you don't have to call spam as a.lut[-1](x). I considered it more likely that the OP would iterate through a.lut and call whatever was callable.  There may well be an unpythonic design error in this approach, or maybe it models his problem quite well.  There's really not enough information to judge.